# Regarding an error in .bib file

Tags: bibliographies, els-cas

I am preparing a manuscript in Elsevier journal template and I started to enter the references to the `.bib` file template given by them. There each entry looks like below.

```
@article{A01,
title   = "A survey on Hamiltonicity in Cayley graphs and digraphs on different groups",
 journal = "Discrete Mathematics, Algorithms and Applications",
 volume  = "",
 number  = "",
 pages   = "",
 year    = "2019",
 doi     = "10.1142/s1793830919300029",
 author  = "G. H. J. Lanel and H. K. Pallage and J. K. Ratnayake and S. Thevasha and B. A. K. Welihinda"
}
```

There since the volume, number and pages information is not available I kept the fields empty as above. But when the PDF is compiled in Latex, in the reference list generated this reference does not show the year of publication either. The reference was visible as

> [2] G.  H.  J.  Lanel,  H.  K.  Pallage,  J.  K.  Ratnayake,  S.  Thevasha,  B.  A.  K.  Weli-hinda,  A  survey  on  hamiltonicity  in  cayley  graphs  and  digraphs  on  differentgroups,  Discrete  Mathematics,  Algorithms  and  Applicationsdoi:10.1142/s1793830919300029

How can I generate the reference including all the information I got?

And also the reference list generated was not arranged in the alphabetical order. Is this due to some problem with the template?

I am using the template available in https://www.elsevier.com/authors/author-schemas/latex-instructions where it can be downloaded by clicking at the end of the sentence which says,

"You can download a set of files containing a template LaTeX manuscript, using the elsarticle class, plus associated BibTeX style files here"

I used the files named "elsarticle-template.tex", "mybibfile.bib" and "numcompress.sty".

Comment: Please tell us which Elsevier template and which bibliography style you use. This is best done in a short, but fully compilable example document. A so-called MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) or MWEB (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864).

Comment: Thank you @moewe I edited the question by adding the link where I got the template. In the .bib file if I add the above mentioned reference where there are no volume, number and pages information, in the reference list it will be added without the year as I mentioned before

Comment: Please be kind enough to advice me to solve this question. Thanks a lot in advance.